# Swi-prolog Type error: `list' expected, found a compound

Tags: prolog, typeerror, swi-prolog

Type error when I try to use the following code to concatenate strings.  The expected behavior is to generate the concatenation of the strings as `FName`.

```
make_file_name(Prefix, Extension, FName) :-
    ( atom(Prefix) ->
          name(Prefix, PrefixStr)
    ; PrefixStr = Prefix
    ),
    ( atom(Extension) ->
          name(Extension, ExtensionStr)
    ; ExtensionStr = Extension
    ),
    append(PrefixStr, ExtensionStr, FNameStr),
    name(FName, FNameStr).
```

The error can be generated like following:

```
➜  chill git:(master) ✗ swipl                                                     [18/06/18| 4:23PM]
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.6.4)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- consult('test_name.pl')
|    .
true.

?- make_file_name('orig-db', "-parser.pl", TestProg).
ERROR: Type error: `list' expected, found `[111,114,105,103,45,100,98|"-parser.pl"]' (a compound)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] name(_3402,[111,114|...])
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

From the error info, it's easy to guess that string `orig-db` is converted to the `ASCII` list.

I can offer a test using `yap` prolog, it's also confusing.

```
➜  chill git:(master) ✗ yap                                                      [18/06/18| 4:03PM]
% Restoring file /usr/lib/Yap/startup.yss
YAP 6.2.2 (x86_64-linux): Sat Sep 17 13:59:03 UTC 2016
   ?- [user].
 % consulting user_input...
| make_file_name(Prefix, Extension, FName) :-
| ( atom(Prefix) ->
|       name(Prefix, PrefixStr)
| ; PrefixStr = Prefix
| ),
| ( atom(Extension) ->
|       name(Extension, ExtensionStr)
| ; ExtensionStr = Extension
| ),
| append(PrefixStr, ExtensionStr, FNameStr),
| name(FName, FNameStr).
| 
 % consulted user_input in module user, 1 msec 9536 bytes
yes
   ?- make_file_name('orig-db', "-parser.pl", TestProg).
no
```

Hope somebody can help with the case. I am new to `prolog` and would like to learn more.

Thank you!

---

*I am trying to migrate an earlier code to `SWI-Prolog`, which was written in
`SICStus 3 #3: Thu Sep 12 09:54:27 CDT 1996` or earlier
by Raymond J. Mooney ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/mooney/chill/. 
All the questions with this tag are all related to this task. I'm new to prolog, helps and suggestions are welcomed!*

Comment: It seems that SWI (version 7+) does not encode strings as a list of codes anymore. String is now a type of its own. See [the SWI documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings).

Comment: @danielp Thank you for the link, according to `As of SWI-Prolog version 7, text enclosed in double quotes (e.g., "Hello world") is read as objects of the type string. `,  I need to pass string with double quote.

Comment: You can use `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes)` or even better `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars)` and at the same time, use `atom_code/2` or `atom_chars/2` in place of `name/2` which is outdated.

Comment: @false Thanks, your method works! Simply using double quoted string will evaluated to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

starting with
swipl --traditional
will solve this one, but there is long way to still
also you can set prolog options related to double quote

this question is quite old, I wonder if you managed to finish building and training it